# How to append multiple child root nodes in an XML file while fetching data from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, xml, dom, xml-serialization, xstream

Am trying to retrieve objects from MySQL database and store it in an XML file. How ever the below code is not writing the XML data in the format i needed.

```html
 private static Document buildCustomerXML(ResultSet EmployeeRS) throws Exception 
  { 

  Document xmlDoc = new DocumentImpl(); 
  
  /* Creating the root element */ 
  
  Element rootElement = xmlDoc.createElement("Schedule"); 
  xmlDoc.appendChild(rootElement);
   while(EmployeeRS.next()) 
    { 
    Element employee1 = xmlDoc.createElement("Employees");
    Element employee = xmlDoc.createElement("Employee"); 

      /* Build the CustomerId as a Attribute*/ 
      employee.setAttribute("id", EmployeeRS.getString("id")); 

      /* Creating elements within customer DOM*/ 
      Element contractid = xmlDoc.createElement("ContractID"); 
      Element lastName = xmlDoc.createElement("Name"); 
      Element skills = xmlDoc.createElement("Skills");
      Element skill = xmlDoc.createElement("Skill");
       /* Populating Customer DOM with Data*/ 
      contractid.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(EmployeeRS.getString("Contractid"))); 
      lastName.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(EmployeeRS.getString("last"))); 
      
      skill.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(EmployeeRS.getString("Skill"))); 
      
      /* Adding the firstname and lastname elements to the Customer Element*/ 
      employee.appendChild(contractid); 
      employee.appendChild(lastName);
     employee.appendChild(skills);
      skills.appendChild(skill);
      employee1.appendChild(employee);
      rootElement.appendChild(employee1);
      
    
     

      /* Appending Customer to the Root Class*/ 
      
     
      /* Build the CustomerId as a Attribute*/ 
      Element constraints1 = xmlDoc.createElement("Constraints"); 
      Element constraints = xmlDoc.createElement("Constraint"); 
      constraints.setAttribute("id", EmployeeRS.getString("id"));
      Element startdat = xmlDoc.createElement("startdate"); 
      startdat.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(EmployeeRS.getString("startdate"))); 
      constraints.appendChild(startdat); 
      constraints1.appendChild(constraints);
     
      rootElement.appendChild(constraints1);
      
    } 
   return xmlDoc; 
   }
```

Below is the output im getting for the above code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Schedule>
    <Employees>
        <Employee id="11">
            <ContractID>1</ContractID>
            <Name>kumbhar</Name>
            <Skills>
                <Skill>Employee</Skill>
            </Skills>
        </Employee>
    </Employees>
    <Constraints>
        <Constraint id="11">
            <startdate>11/08/2014</startdate>
        </Constraint>
    </Constraints>
    <Employees>
        <Employee id="14">
            <ContractID>1</ContractID>
            <Name>Raje</Name>
            <Skills>
                <Skill>Employee</Skill>
            </Skills>
        </Employee>
    </Employees>
    <Constraints>
        <Constraint id="14">
            <startdate>2014-11-12</startdate>
        </Constraint>
    </Constraints>
</Schedule>
```

However i need output to be in the below form

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Schedule>

    <Employees>
        <Employee id="11">
            <ContractID>1</ContractID>
            <Name>kumbhar</Name>
            <Skills>
                <Skill>Employee</Skill>
            </Skills>
        </Employee>   
        <Employee id="14">
            <ContractID>1</ContractID>
            <Name>Raje</Name>
            <Skills>
                <Skill>Employee</Skill>
            </Skills>
        </Employee>
    </Employees>
    
    
    <Constraints>
        <Constraint id="14">
            <startdate>2014-11-12</startdate>
        </Constraint>        
        <Constraint id="11">
            <startdate>11/08/2014</startdate>
        </Constraint>
   
    </Constraints>
</Schedule>
```

Can any one provide me suggestions on how to achieve output in the above format

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```html
 while(EmployeeRS.next()) 
    { 
    
    Element employee = xmlDoc.createElement("Employee"); 

      /* Build the CustomerId as a Attribute*/ 
      employee.setAttribute("id", EmployeeRS.getString("id")); 

      /* Creating elements within customer DOM*/ 
      Element contractid = xmlDoc.createElement("ContractID"); 
      Element lastName = xmlDoc.createElement("Name"); 
      Element skills = xmlDoc.createElement("Skills");
      Element skill = xmlDoc.createElement("Skill");
       /* Populating Customer DOM with Data*/ 
      contractid.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(EmployeeRS.getString("Contractid"))); 
      lastName.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(EmployeeRS.getString("last"))); 
      
      skill.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(EmployeeRS.getString("Skill"))); 
      
      /* Adding the firstname and lastname elements to the Customer Element*/ 
      employee.appendChild(contractid); 
      employee.appendChild(lastName);
     employee.appendChild(skills);
      skills.appendChild(skill);
      employee1.appendChild(employee);
      
           /* Appending Customer to the Root Class*/ 
      
     
      /* Build the CustomerId as a Attribute*/ 
      
      Element constraints = xmlDoc.createElement("Constraint"); 
      constraints.setAttribute("id", EmployeeRS.getString("id"));
      Element startdat = xmlDoc.createElement("startdate"); 
      Element enddat = xmlDoc.createElement("enddate"); 
      startdat.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(EmployeeRS.getString("startdate"))); 
      enddat.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(EmployeeRS.getString("enddate"))); 
      constraints.appendChild(startdat);
      constraints.appendChild(enddat);
      constraints1.appendChild(constraints);
      
      
     
      
      
    } rootElement.appendChild(employee1);
    rootElement.appendChild(constraints1);
   return xmlDoc;
   }
```